# how to join tables where foreign key is not unique in one table in Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables (products and locations) from where I need to get all the products and locations where the products are available at once.
The product table looks like this:

```
Product| Price | Product_id
  Rice | 45.00 | 101
  Beans| 30.00 | 102
```

and the Locations table looks like this:

```
Product_id | location
101        | Chicago
101        | Paris
101        | Lagos
102        | London
102        | New York
```

I'm using Laravel Eloquent Model to try to solve this but I keep getting multiple rows of the same product.

**What I want to get as a result:**

```
$result = 
{ 
  {"Rice", 
    45.00, 
    101, 
    location: {"Chicago", "Paris", "Lagos"}
  },
  {"Beans", 
    30.00, 
    102, 
    location: {"London", "New York"}
  }
}
```

Any help rendered would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Correct way it would by change database to 3 tables and make many to many relationship. Because I think from Chicago can be more than one product.
So table products, table locations, and table location_product (id, location_id, product_id)

Comment: Can you show your current query and the code for your models?

Comment: @Autista_z  Could you show me with a working example how to get the full result in one select statement via your method.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you want to retrieve models. So firstly create your product and location model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    // if you have no standard table naming
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function products()
    {
        // you have to specify the foreign key is Product id as it does not follow the laravel standard
        $this->hasMany(Location::class, 'Product_id');
    }
}

class Location extends Model
{
    // if you have no standard table naming
    protected $table = 'locations';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'Product_id');
    }
}
```

This means you can now retrieve your product. With include the locations so it will perform optimal.

```
$products = Product::with('locations')->get();
```

Now products will have multiple locations as the way the tables bind together. You can retrieve em like so. For a structure similar to yours. Thou your JSON is not valid at all.

```
$products = $products->map(function($product) {
    $product->location = $product->locations->map(function($location){
        return $location->location;
    });

    return $product;
})
```

You still probably want to transform the products into a pretty JSON response, for now this seems fitting compared to the question in mind.

Comment: I agree that this should be made as a many to many relationship, but the original questions ask how to retrieve it in the following column structure, thats how you would do it the Laravel way.

Since this is a pretty basic question, i feel like it is important to take baby steps.

Comment: Hey @Martin Henriksen, I understand what you just did here but I want to be able to get the full result in one select statement. Showing me a working example would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your json is not valid and this more and more seems like you are not interested in learning how to fix your problem, more so that you want someone to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input Martin. I kinda found out how to make it work without having to manipulate my model structure. Apologies if you feel that way. I'm gonna accept your answer because I got a clue of how to solve my problem from your code sample.

Comment: If you took my example and got something out of it, you have the right mindset :) hope it helped have a good day.